# Implementation of Sum of divisor algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was trying to implement the sum of divisors algorithm in c++ i.e.,

> Let n = p1^a1 * p2^a2 * .... * pk^ak
>
> Then
>
> σ(n) = ( (p1^(a1+1) -
>    1) / (p1-1) ) * ( (p2^(a2+1) - 1) / (p2-1) ) * ... * ( (pk^(ak+1) - 1) / (pk-1) )

The function for prime factorization that pushes factor in a `vector<int> p`

```
void primeFactors(int n)
{
    while (n%2 == 0)
    {
        p.push_back(2);
        n = n/2;
    }
    for (ull i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)
    {
        while (n%i == 0)
        {
            p.push_back(i);
            n = n/i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 2)
        p.push_back(n);
}
```

Then I create a copy of `vector<int> p` in `vector<int> pk` as `vector<int> pk(p)` and do following to have only unique elements in p.

```
auto it = unique(p.begin(),p.end());
 p.resize(distance(p.begin(),it) );
```

Now the final to get sum as per the formula:

```
for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++){
        sum *= (pow(p[i],count(pk.begin(), pk.end(), p[i]))-1)/(p[i]-1);
    }
```

The above implemention is wrong as I am not getting correct output. Where am I making a mistake? Is their a better method for implementing it?

Comment: Where am I making a mistake? Not running it under a debugger.

Comment: I tried all I could but I am not getting correct output

Comment: Try printing the p vector to see if its OK, `std::copy(std::begin(p),std::end(p), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));cout << std::endl;`.

Comment: Why `for(int i=1;i<=p.size();i++)` and not `for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++)`??

Comment: oh! my mistake. Corrected it but still not getting correct sum.

Comment: You write "only unique elements in pk" but you make `p` unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final loop for calculating the result is `pi^ai` instead of `pi^(ai+1)`. Change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++){
    sum *= (pow(p[i], count(pk.begin(), pk.end(), p[i]) + 1) - 1) / (p[i] - 1);
}
```

One more thing, instead of using vectors and using `unique` and `count` you can simply use a `map<int, int>` and instead of getting the number of occurrences of each prime number in O(n) get it in O(lgn) like this:

```
void primeFactors(int n, map<int, int> &facs){
    facs.clear();
    for (long long p = 2; p*p <= n; p++){
        while (n%p == 0){
            facs[p] ++;
            n /= p;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1)
        facs[n] = 1;
}

long long getRes(map<int, int> &facs){
    long long t, res = 1;
    for (auto it = facs.begin(); it != facs.end(); ++it){
        t = pow(it->first, it->second + 1) - 1;
        t /= (it->first - 1);
        res *= t;
    }
    return res;
}
```

In the above code I also used `pow` function for calculating the result. We can eliminate this function by storing power values instead of count in the map, like this:

```
void primeFactors(int n, map<int, long long> &facs){
    facs.clear();
    for (long long p = 2; p*p <= n; p++){
        while (n%p == 0){
            if (facs.count(p))//this way we can save pi^(ai+1) instead of counting prime numbers
                facs[p] *= p;
            else
                facs[p] = p*p;
            n /= p;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1)
        facs[n] = n*n;
}

long long getRes(map<int, long long> &facs){
    long long t, res = 1;
    for (auto it = facs.begin(); it != facs.end(); ++it){
        t = it->second - 1;  //this is for pi^(ai+1)-1
        t /= (it->first - 1);
        res *= t;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about maps

Comment: Maps can store <key, value> pairs. In this program we use prime numbers as keys and their count as values.